# Neural Network training: mini-batch loss is same, mini-batch accuracy is different

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, gradient-descent

I wrote a simple neural network using tensor flow. During the training I see that mini-batch loss stays the same but mini-batch accuracy is different.

Example:

```
Step 62000, Mini-batch Loss = 0.6931, Training Accuracy = 0.910
Step 63000, Mini-batch Loss = 0.6931, Training Accuracy = 0.909
Step 64000, Mini-batch Loss = 0.6931, Training Accuracy = 0.918
Step 65000, Mini-batch Loss = 0.6931, Training Accuracy = 0.910
```

Seems a bit weird for me. Is it fine or not? What do you think?
Just a small comment: I am using Adam and batching..so not all the training examples are calculated in one iteration..

Here is the code:

```
layers_output = {'A0': X}
for i in range(1, hidden_layers + 2):
    Z = tf.add(tf.matmul(layers_output['A' + str(i - 1)], weights['W' + str(i)]), biases['b' + str(i)])
    if i == hidden_layers + 1:
        layers_output['A' + str(i)] = tf.sigmoid(Z)
    else:
        layers_output['A' + str(i)] = tf.tanh(Z)
logits = layers_output['A' + str(hidden_layers + 1)]
prediction = tf.round(logits)

# Define loss and optimizer
loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=Y))
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate, beta1=beta1, beta2=beta2).minimize(loss_op)

# Evaluate model
correct_pred = tf.equal(prediction, Y)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    mini_batches = divide_into_mini_batches(X_train, Y_train, mini_batch_size)
    for step in range(1, num_steps + 1):
        batch_x = mini_batches[step % len(mini_batches)][0]
        batch_y = mini_batches[step % len(mini_batches)][1]
        # Run optimization op (backprop)
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y: batch_y})
        if step % display_step == 0 or step == 1:
            # Calculate batch loss and accuracy
            loss, acc = sess.run([loss_op, accuracy], feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y: batch_y})
            print("Step " + str(step) + ", Mini-batch Loss = " +
                  "{:.4f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy = " +
                  "{:.3f}".format(acc))
```

Thanks

Comment: you must be having problem with your optimizer, gradient-descent is not right.